# Unable to retrieve coordinates from Markers

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-maps-markers

I'm pretty new to react, so maybe I'm just blind to some kind of brackening, that I'm not seeing, but it would be great if you could help me with this.

So what I am trying is to start Google Maps outside my application with the current location of the user and the specific destination of a marker. Right now it does starts directing in Maps outside my application and it takes the current location from the user, but I'm having problems with retrieving the location from the Markers. (I think) I know where the problem is but I get an error everytime I try.

In my one screen, I have the following function

```
export default class ParkingLot extends React.Component {
    state = {
        info: null,
        coordinates: null
    }

    onInfo(info, coordinates) {
        this.setState({ info, coordinates})
    }
```

So now I would need the coordinates to go into my Markers Component, but that is not working.

```
 <Marker
      key={parkingLot.name}
      coordinate={firstParkingSpace}
      onPress={() => { onInfo(getInfo(parkingLot, navigate) //coordinates should go here (I guess))}}
    >
```

Hope you get what I mean and can help somehow. Thanks in advance

Comment: The commented end brackets on the `onPress` line are only here on SO or in your app code ? Also you are only sending the first `info` parameter to `onInfo` you are not sending the coordinates

Comment: `onInfo(getInfo(...), coordinates)` if you need more help I will need more info about both of the components

Comment: The thing is by simply putting ```onInfo(getInfo(...), coordinates)```  it gives out an error, saying that it can't find the variable

Comment: try  `onPress={(e) => console.log(e)}` The coordinates should be somewhere inside `e`. After you find them you can pass them as second argument to `onInfo`